# Get specific value from function

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was trying to do this:

```
def get_sum_col(col):
    val = ""
    cont = ""
    for x in range(1, mxrw1):
        if type(ws_Sheet1.cell(row=x, column=col).value) == int or type(
                ws_Sheet1.cell(row=x, column=col).value) == float:
            if val == "":
                cont = 1
                val = ws_Sheet1.cell(row=x, column=col).value
            else:
                cont += 1
                val = int(val) + int(ws_Sheet1.cell(row=x, column=col).value)
    media = int(val) / int(cont)
    return val, media
```

And then to get the value i need something like

```
print(get_sum_col(3).media
print(get_sum_col(3).val
```

is this possible?
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
def get_sum_col(col):
    ...
    return {'val': val, 'media': media}

print(get_sum_col(3).get('media', None) # None will print if media is bull
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val, media = get_sum_col(3)

print(val)

print(media)
```

Or you can make get_sum_col an object.

Comment: Add more details in your answer, and it would be nice if you format your code properly.

Answer (score 2):

`val, media = get_sum_col(3)` will only call your function once but will initialize the val and media variables to the return value from the function.

by the way - you can call those variables in any name in your caller code.

Answer (score 2):

Returning two variables doesn't return an object: it's returning a tuple. `val, media` is shorthand for `(val, media)`. You can just turn the tuple back into two variables like so:

```
def get_sum_col(col);
    ...
    return val, media
...
val, media = get_sum_col(col)
```